Almacenar con laravel imagenes en la carpeta de react y no puedo acceder
estoy haciendo una app con laravel y react, almaceno el nombre del archivo de las imagenes en el backend y almaceno con laravel las imagenes dentro de la carpeta de react, de la siguiente manera:
public function store(StoreImagenRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    
    $discoteca = Discoteca::findOrFail($data['discoteca_id']);

    $imageData = [];
    if($files = $request->file('imagen')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
            
            
            // Guarda la imagen modificada en su lugar
            Storage::disk('img_boliches')->put($filename, File::get($file));

            $imageData[] = [
                'discoteca_id' => $discoteca->id,
                'imagen' => $filename
            ];
        }
    }        

    $imagen = ImagenDiscoteca::insert( $imageData );

    return response()->json($imagen);
}

    'img_boliches' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => base_path() . '/react/src/assets/img_boliches', // Actualiza esto a la ruta de tu carpeta
    ],

Al intentar leer alguna de las imagenes guardadas no me las reconoce a pesar de que si queden almacenadas correctamente:
src="../../../assets/img_boliches/1715371339.jpg"

accedo de forma correcta a alguna de las imagenes que cargue por mi formulario de upload de imagenes y no la muestra, pero si descargo una imagen de google y la intento usar si funciona
aqui si utilizo una imagen descargada de google:
src"../../../assets/img_boliches/descarga.jpg`"



Lo que se acostumbra es utilizar un servicio para almacenar las imágenes que después obtendrás mediante url para mostrar en tu aplición.
No estás compartiendo la estructura de tus proyectos pero por cuestiones de buenas prácticas no deberían estar mezclados.
Cuando vas a almacenar tus imágenes de forma local se utiliza el driver local de laravel, tal cual lo haces en tu código, normalmente los archivos se almacenan en la carpeta storage/app de tu proyecto de laravel y desde ahí puedes hacer las operaciones típicas de archivos (leer, modificar, eliminar).

Explicado lo anterior, entonces:
Para obtener las imágenes desde tu disco local (storage/app) y mostrarlas en tu aplicación de react puedes obtener la imágen y después convertirla a base64 para retornarla desde tu controlador y mostrarla en el frente.
En el backend:
public function base64Encode($fileName){
    $file = Storage::get($filename);
    // Comprueba que el archivo exista antes de intentar convertirlo
    
    return base64_encode($file);
}

En el frontend:
<img src={`data:image/jpg;base64,${image}`}/>

image es la variable que contiene la imágen en base64 enviada desde el backend. Ten en cuenta que aquí utilice image/jpg porque supuse que la imágen es .jpg pero si no lo es debes hacer que coincida con el formato de la imágen que envias desde el backend.
